# Install the msi package only if a another one was installed

Tags: package, installshield

I have 2 msi packages 1 called the core package in which i want the second package to check before installation if the core package is installed, if yes then the installation occurs normally, if not then the second package wont be installed telling me that you need to install the core package first before installing,

just for clarification when installing the core package some files goes to a specific location so i can check the existence of these files in their location when installing the second package if the files exists then install the second package and if not then the second package wont install and say that you need to install the core package first before installing and exits,

Can any one help me please as this is the first time to use install shield,

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- use a search to detect if the core package was installed
- use that search property as a custom launch condition

This way the package installation will stop and show a message if core package was not installed.

Another approach is to add the secondary package as a custom prerequisite for the core package.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do so-->"search to detect if the core package was installed" thanks alot